# What celestial body did NASA carve and why is it eating a spacecraft?

Tags: nasa, identify-this-object, space-art

The Mashable.com article [No one carves a Halloween pumpkin like NASA engineers](https://mashable.com/article/halloween-pumpkin-nasa-engineers) shows several interesting examples.

But this one I can't figure out. The caption reads only.

> Om nom nom.

**Question:** Can someone identify this celestial object and the spacecraft it is eating?

[image]

**above:** IMAGE: NASA/JPL-CALTECH, [Source](https://mashable.com/article/halloween-pumpkin-nasa-engineers)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That's Saturn eating Cassini (remember Cassini's entry into Saturn's atmosphere at the end of its mission).

Comment: Oh! and those are *rings* on it's head, got it. That was 15-Sep-2017, just over a year ago.

Comment: Are the gummy worms supposed to be satellite blood? Or what are those? Kind of looks like a goatee. I figure they have a purpose.

Comment: A coarse attempt at the north polar hexagon?  (Sure, it's in the wrong place relative to the ring, but the ring's in the wrong place, too..)

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn the ring looks a bit like a sombrero. The worms' colours remind of the Mexican flag. Coincidence?

Comment: @IMil: Bow to the might of Mexican Saturn!